# Scatterplot in RStudio with ggplot function

Tags: r, variables, scatter-plot, exploratory

I'm trying to see that there is any correlation between the education level and cholesterol awareness using data from the Behavioral Risk Factor Surveillance System for 2013 dataset. The contents of the data can be checked from the link down below:
https://d18ky98rnyall9.cloudfront.net/_e34476fda339107329fc316d1f98e042_brfss_codebook.html?Expires=1541203200&Signature=WYq5YJFg5WgVOFV4dWPV~pPtu-31ubNEVxEYlNliJZpqZYXfZ741WN9n~RC~kcF0gE6AdxzzNFbiA7nv5DtQsxeWWs1Y9obwadm2PjV8eO~W0TI0YtyU~vmaWgozEkfbzIB17LP0MFY-dUffEsyb29~~JWYnQXHAZXdm-n5q108_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A##sleptim1

There are two variables what I used for EDA: "educa"(Education Level) and "cholchk"(How Long Since Cholesterol Checked). And this is the code what I created:

```
> q1 <- select(brfss2013, cholchk, educa) %>%
        filter(!is.na(cholchk), !is.na(educa))

> q1 %>% group_by(cholchk) %>%    summary(count=n())

> ggplot(data = q1, aes(x = educa, y = cholchk)) +
    geom_point(shape=1) +
    geom_smooth(method=1) +
    xlab("educa = Education Level") +
    ylab ("cholchk: How Long Since Cholesterol Checked")
```

The graph was successfully created. But all dots on the graph are spread at regular intervals(?), so it's unable to check correlation. Could you give me some advice to get a better look than this?

[scatterplot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh761.png)

I don't know how to upload ".RData" file on my question. So this is the best I can do.

cholchk
 Within past year   :321955
 Within past 2 years: 49354
 Within past 5 years: 29870
 5 or more years ago: 15683

educa
 Never attended school or only kindergarten                  :   463
 Grades 1 through 8 (Elementary)                             : 10189
 Grades 9 though 11 (Some high school)                       : 21173
 Grade 12 or GED (High school graduate)                      :117152
 College 1 year to 3 years (Some college or technical school):113993
 College 4 years or more (College graduate)                  :153892

Comment: That upper link throws an error.

Comment: You might need a) get some statistical consultation, and b) use a jittering function.

Comment: Can you add sample data sets?

Comment: dbeginner, the link returns "Access Denied", but I'm not asking you to fix that problem. In general, questions on SO should not link to data: when the link dies, the question becomes unreproducible. Can you please post some representative sample data from your data? A good sample might be the output from `dput(head(brfss2013[c("cholchk","educa")],n=30)`, with the assumption that 30 rows presents enough variability. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: The dataset file is brfss2013.RData, so I don't know how to upload it.

Comment: @dbeginner: you need to read and follow the guide in the links r2evans posted. Otherwise no one will be able to help you. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5).